# Adjusting length of HTML page depending upon the content

Tags: html, css

Am designing a site and am quite new to it. So my question may be naive. There are two pages `index.html` and `aboutUs.html`.

For this eg, i have removed most of the invalid contents with regards to my question. My question is related to how can we dynamically change or handle the length of the page based on the content. In my case, `index.html` does not have too much text, so the UI looks fine, however `aboutUS.html` has too much content, and the content **overlaps** with the footer. **How do I handle such scenarios?** For reference, I have added some images below, the first image has no overlap, but the second one has. You can find the source code over at [GitHub](https://github.com/vnmshenoy/global) (https://github.com/vnmshenoy/global)

#### Images

[image: No overlap]

[image: With overlap]

Comment: Elements in HTML are automatically responsive to their contents and neighbours unless you predefine your heights. I am not going to look through your entire site code (you should only post/link the relevant code tbh), but I'm assuming your content has a fixed height which means it does not expand and therefor does not push the footer down.

Comment: there are few way to solve this but a quick point is use min-height for your all pages so it will manage if there is not much content or else normal is ok..

Comment: Thanks "somethinghere", the only code what matters is in  these two html files i,e in index and aboutus.html. I posted the whole  full code for  your reference only(if needed)

Comment: I think you have give scroll to inner content which has much height so it will scroll not overlap

Comment: well,  you have used too many static width and height and even much complicated code for simple page. Try to sit relax and check and then you can solve it. Sorry can't chcek whole site so..sorry

Comment: Thanks "Leo". But i didn;t get your whole point. Do you mean to say that I need to use min-height for both pages ? i,e say for <body>element? Please clarify

Comment: its ok no probs Leo :-)

Comment: First off, if you want to grab someones attention here, use `@` in front of their name. Lucky I came back. Heres are the two main culprits you will discover: positioning other than `static` or `relative` and fixed heights (aka an actual number). Check your code for those. Again, there is too much code there to go through, so please ask another question once you have tried to work this out yourself. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your problematic classes seem to be imageDiv and overlap.
Both these have defined heights.

When the content inside the element is larger than this height, it is visible, but is actually spilling outside that position, and so appears on top of the next element.  If you set a border on these elements, you will see what I mean.

You could always use the overflow:scroll style here and scrollbars will appear when this happens, but you'd be better making your design a bit more fluid with regard to heights, especially if you plan to make it responsive.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Will try that out

Comment: If you are in Firefox, I'd recommend you use Firebug - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ - it really helps with debugging and finding out what styles are being applied where.  Other browsers will have similar tools.